# Wordpress Multisite Redirect Loop error on subsites, not main site

Tags: localhost, wamp, wordpress, redirect-loop

I'm building a WordPress Multisite locally using WAMP 2.2 and WP 3.5. It was a fresh WP installation and uses subdirectories for the new sites. I am able to view the Network dashboard and the main blog dashboard and site. I can view the sub-sites but when I try to go to their dashboards I get the 310/redirect loop error message.

So these URLs work fine:

```
http://localhost/www.bloggersofhealth.org/

http://localhost/www.bloggersofhealth.org/wp-admin/

http://localhost/www.bloggersofhealth.org/areliaj/
```

But this one times out and gives the redirect loop error:

```
http://localhost/www.bloggersofhealth.org/areliaj/wp-admin/
```

The problem sites were all created a few days ago, so to make sure I hadn't made some change to those sites I created a new test sub-site just now and it has the same problem.

I've read about others with this problem and I have verified

- Apache rewrite module is checked
- I checked the blogs and options tables and both show localhost as the domain and correct file paths and no www in the URLs
- I read in another post that adding www fixed the issue but I understand you can't do that using localhost
- I checked htacess has

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /www.bloggersofhealth.org/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  ```
- I checked wpconfig has

  ```
  define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
  define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
  define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/www.bloggersofhealth.org/');
  ```

I'm new to WordPress, WAMP and PHP but I'll eagerly work with any advice that's given because I'd like to become proficient in all three.